# How to exclude values from a data frame based on an order/sequence

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a data frame in R that looks something like this

| PatientID | Date | Dose | Creatinine |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 02.08.23 | NA | 65 |
| 101 | 03.08.23 | 1000 | NA |
| 101 | 04.08.23 | 1000 | NA |
| 101 | 04.08.23 | NA | 68 |
| 102 | 10.09.23 | NA | 89 |
| 102 | 10.09.23 | 1000 | NA |

With multiple rows for each patient, and only one type of variable is recorded in each line.

For every patientID, I want to remove the creatinine values that are recorded before the day of the first dose. So for patient 101 I want to remove the first creatine value, for patient 102 I want to  keep the first creatinine value.

I know that there could be maximum one creatinine value that is recorded before the first dose, so I just need to check the first creatinine value for each of the patients, if it is recorded before the first dose. I just don't understand how to do it!

The reason I need to do is to compute the mean of the creatinine values for each patient, excluding the values I explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your `Date` variable is a date object this can be done simply using `filter`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |> 
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%m.%d.%y")) |>
  filter(Date >= Date[which(!is.na(Dose))[1]], .by = PatientID)
```

`Date[which(!is.na(Dose))[1]]` finds the index of the first non-NA dose and then uses that index to find the corresponding date. Note: this assumes your data are pre-sorted in ascending order (which it is in your example).

**Output**

```
  PatientID       Date Dose Creatinine
1       101 2023-03-08 1000         NA
2       101 2023-04-08 1000         NA
3       101 2023-04-08   NA         68
4       102 2023-10-09   NA         89
5       102 2023-10-09 1000         NA
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(PatientID = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L
), Date = c("02.08.23", "03.08.23", "04.08.23", "04.08.23", "10.09.23", 
"10.09.23"), Dose = c(NA, 1000L, 1000L, NA, NA, 1000L), Creatinine = c(65L, 
NA, NA, 68L, 89L, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the easiest one for me to implement!

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    # assuming your dates are m.d.y rather than d.m.y
    Date = as.Date(Date, "%m.%d.%y"),
    DoseDate = min(Date[!is.na(Dose)]),
    Creatinine = if_else(Date >= DoseDate, Creatinine, NA),
    .by = PatientID
  )
```

Result:

```
  PatientID       Date Dose Creatinine   DoseDate
1       101 2023-02-08   NA         NA 2023-03-08
2       101 2023-03-08 1000         NA 2023-03-08
3       101 2023-04-08 1000         NA 2023-03-08
4       101 2023-04-08   NA         68 2023-03-08
5       102 2023-10-09   NA         89 2023-10-09
6       102 2023-10-09 1000         NA 2023-10-09
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go purely by position, you could define a function to eliminate any NA value (in  `Dose`) before the first non-NA value:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_table("PatientID     Date    Dose    Creatinine
101     01.08.23    NA  34
101     02.08.23    NA  65
101     03.08.23    1000    NA
101     04.08.23    1000    NA
101     04.08.23    NA  68
102     10.09.23    NA  89
102     10.09.23    1000    NA")

after_first_dose <- function(x) {
  after_first <- !is.na(x)
  cumsum(after_first) >= 1
}

df |> 
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) |> 
  arrange(PatientID, Date) |> 
  filter(after_first_dose(Dose))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   PatientID Date        Dose Creatinine
#>       <dbl> <date>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1       101 2023-03-08  1000         NA
#> 2       101 2023-04-08  1000         NA
#> 3       101 2023-04-08    NA         68
#> 4       102 2023-10-09    NA         89
#> 5       102 2023-10-09  1000         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Alternatively, you could use a non-equi join to match creatinine values recorded after the first dose:

```r
first_dose <- df |> select(!Creatinine) |> filter(!is.na(Dose)) |> slice_head(n = 1, by = PatientID)
creatinine <- df |> select(!Dose) |> filter(!is.na(Creatinine))

first_dose |> 
  left_join(creatinine, join_by(PatientID, Date <= Date))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   PatientID Date.x      Dose Date.y     Creatinine
#>       <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>          <dbl>
#> 1       101 2023-03-08  1000 2023-04-08         68
#> 2       102 2023-10-09  1000 2023-10-09         89
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>